# uniqueidentifier in SQL becomes lower case in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have column(uniqueidentifier) in SQL which stored guid. I see that it's in upper case. But when the data is returned through SP to C# code, it becomes lower case

I am using entity framework in data access. What could be the reason and can I avoid this conversion?

Comment: The uniqueidentifer is not case sensitive. Do you experience any problems?

Comment: I understand that uniqueidentifier is not case sensitive. when I select the data, I see it in upper case. The consumer of my code is have some problems because the SP returns in lower case and in some other call he is getting data in upper case. So where is the conversion happening?

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` from sql server is `GUID` in .NET. `GUID` is just a number, formatted as hex value with some dashes added for easier reading. `abc12` is exactly the same as `ABC12` - if you are using `GUID` type. If you are converting it to `string` and then doing some operations in `C#` you should stop doig it that way - it's not how it is supposed to be

Comment: Case sensitivity can matter if uniqueidentity is used a password hashing salt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you using Entity Framework, `uniqueidentifier` data will convert to Guid.

> The value of this Guid, represented as a series of lowercase
>   hexadecimal digits in the specified format.

If you need consistency in your application you can use one format when you get string out of Guid.

Check [**Guid.ToString Method (String)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess.aspx)  for available formats

There can be a place where you get guid as string from database so that will be infinity upper case. ( check stored procedures Views etc..)

To avoid this issue you have to make sure that return `uniqueidentifier` as it is, don't convert to varchar and also follow one stranded format when converting to string.

For other operations like comparing etc..You can use Guid operators..

Comment: What do u mean by  "make sure that return guid as uniqueidentifier"?In DD its uniqueindentifier.

Comment: You may have places where uniqueidentifier converted to varchar in db level and return to your program. Then you have this issue if you not convert it to lower case.

Comment: In C#, `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` returns string in lower case; and in SQL server, `SELECT NEWID()` returns string in upper case. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that SQL Server stores a uniqueidentifier as a 128-bit integer and then converts it to hexadecimal for display. As Alexander says, it doesn't matter whether it displays this hexadecimal value in upper-case or lower-case as they represent the same thing.

If it matters to your application, then you can convert it to upper-case in C# without a problem.